# How to truncate restart Identity and cascade in pydal

Tags: python, sqlite, pydal

What am I doing wrong? I am sure its just a simpile sytanx error.

Help is appreciated

```
db.venues.truncate("RESTARTIDENTITYCASCADE")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your command is all globed together without spaces. This [link](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer?search=restart) shows the command as:

```
db.venues.truncate('RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE')
```